# copy files from tftp server

Tags: boot, pxe, tftp

AFAIU, When `tftp` server is used for `pxe` booting, the client sends a request to the server, and the server sends back few files (initrd, kernel, config, ...). The server can decide which files to send to the client depending on the IP address of the client. The client does not know the URL of those files.

My questions is this:

I would like to test `tftp` server. I would like to run a command, or a (simple) script which contacts the `tftp` server, and receives the files, and saves these files on the disk.

In other word what I want to do is this:

- On the server side, there is no difference: the server thinks the client wants to boot over PXE and sends the files to the client
- On the client side: the client does not actually want to boot. It just wants to copy (save) the files to disk.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I would use the tftp client to do this. An example of connecting to the server is shown here: http://mohammadthalif.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/installing-and-testing-tftpd-in-ubuntudebian/

Comment: I think you have some misunderstandings about how PXE booting works. The tftp server doesn't push files to the client. The boot server offers a DHCP lease which contains the filenames it needs to go and download. You might be able to get that information if you can find a dhcp client with some sort of debug output option.

Comment: @Patrick - the DHCP server has a `next-server` record, which is an IP address of the tftp server. I know the IP address of my tftp server already, so I can ignore the part involving `DHCP` entirely. How do I get the list of filenames from the `tftp` server ?

Comment: I just told you, it's in the DHCP lease.

Comment: @Patrick - this cannot be true. The `DHCP` server has no idea which boot image a client gets from the `tftp` server. That is decided by the tftp server (i.e., depending on the clients IP). The `DHCP` server only knows the IP address of the `tftp` server, and the location of the `pxelinux.0` file. That entry is called "next-server".

Comment: No it is not decided by the tftp server. The tftp server is an extremely basic file server, hence the "trivial" part of the name. The DHCP server determines which file gets sent based on MAC address.

Comment: @Patrick - I am 100% sure what you say is wrong. I am running my own tftp server and I know how it works. The `tftp` protocol must be extremely basic/trivial, so that clients can be simple. But the server does not need to be basic. Indeed my tftp server decides what boot image client gets, depending on IP. I am using `tftpd-hpa`.

Comment: If you already know exactly how it works, then why are you asking for our help? Please go read the [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1350) before you continue this debate.

Answer (score 3):

The comment @Patrick made to your question was dead right: all the client machine needs to bootstrap PXE is to broadcast a DHCP request. The DHCP server (usually on the PXE boot server) will see the MAC address of the client device and will use it to

- give the client an IP address
- tell the client what files it should get from the PXE server

at that point, the client knows the address of the server and what to get from it. Unfortunately, there are a bunch of fiddly bits like there can be only one DHCP server which has the special configuration for the PXE client, a TFTP server needs to be running and so on.

There is a pretty good step by step guide at https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall. You didn't specify your distro, but most PXE systems will at least rhyme with that guide.

I know that your question says you don't want to know the address of the PXE server. But there is only one way (without writing your own client) that can be done, with a PXE client DHCP requester/processor. If you want to forego that part you throw away much of the capabilites needed to get you bootstrapped.

I know that you don't actually want to boot the machine which puts you in the position of implementing a lot of the PXE protocol for testing purposes. If you don't have a scratch machine available, I'm curious as to why you need to test PXE at all.

Comment: I have checked my `DHCP` server, and actually, the `next-server` entry contains only two things: 1) IP address of the `tftp` server, and 2) path to `pxelinux.0` on the server. I know both. So I can skip the part with `DHCP`. But how will I get the list of files from the `tftp` server? It is the `tftp` server who decides which files to offer me (depending on my IP address. I don't know which files these are, or their URL.

Comment: What list of files? `pxelinux.0` is all that there is.

Comment: the list/URL of the boot image files. `pxelinux.0` is just a loader (like lilo or grub). I need to retrieve the actual initrd and kernel files from the `tftp` server.

Comment: There is no list. Yes, pxelinux.0 is a bootloader. It is completely up to whatever code the PXE client pulls down whether it fetches anything else. If `pxelinux.0` doesn't want to fetch anything, then it doesn't. You have to run it to determine if it wants to fetch anything else.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a real `tftp` client?

Those two which come to my mind:

- [`tftp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tftp)
- [`atftp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/atftp)

Comment: but to use the tftp client, I need to know the URL of the files. But my whole point is, that the server thinks I am booting from PXE and sends me the files I need (depending on my IP address). I don't know which files it will be.

Comment: Unfortunately, that PXE booting involves other protocols as well (DHCP/BOOTP in this case). Either you know what the DHCP reply will contain (as you're administering that as well), so you know which TFTP server to ask (IP address), and which files to get, or you'll have to use some kind of command-line DHCP client as well (I used `busybox udhcpc` in a similar situation).

Answer (score 1):

I'm most familiar with how [Cobbler](http://www.cobblerd.org/) sets up TFTP so I'm not sure if this is relevant but I'll offer this info up anyway. Cobbler sets up a bootloader using `pxelinux.0` as [@Patrick explains in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159725/copy-files-from-tftp-server/159840#comment261729_159725) as well as [@msw](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159740/7453). But it also sets up a corresponding `pxelinux.cfg/` directory along side it that contains MAC addresses for each system that will be connecting to the server.

These files contain `pxelinux.cfg` file info like this:

```
$ more 01-54-52-00-ff-ff-ff
default linux
prompt 0
timeout 1
label linux
        kernel /images/Centos56-x86_64/vmlinuz
        ipappend 2
        append initrd=/images/Centos56-x86_64/initrd.img ksdevice=bootif lang=  console=ttyS0,115200 text serial kssendmac  ks=http://192.168.1.207/cblr/svc/op/ks/system/kvmcobblertest
```

The actual Linux kernel that this VM will boot is contained in this TFTP accessible directory, `/images/Centos56-x86_64/vmlinuz`. The entire TFTP directory structure looks like this from the backside of the server:

```
$ ls -l /tftpboot/
total 348
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jun 22  2011 etc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jul  9  2012 grub
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root   4096 Jul  9  2012 images
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jun 30  2011 images2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20020 Jul  9  2012 memdisk
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39188 Jul  9  2012 menu.c32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jun 22  2011 ppc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14716 Jul  9  2012 pxelinux.0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jul  9  2012 pxelinux.cfg
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jul  9  2012 s390x
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 198192 Jul  9  2012 yaboot
```

The only thing that's initially accessible by the servers that are booting against this TFTP server, is as other's have described, the `pxelinux.0` + the configuration file that corresponds to a particular server's MAC address.

#### Images directory

This looks like this if you're curious:

```
$ tree /tftpboot/images
/tftpboot/images
|-- Centos56-x86_64
|   |-- initrd.img
|   `-- vmlinuz
|-- Centos56-xen-x86_64
|   |-- initrd.img
|   `-- vmlinuz
`-- Centos60-x86_64
    |-- initrd.img
    `-- vmlinuz

3 directories, 6 files
```